# Firebase retrieval

Tags: java, android, firebase

This is Firebase data:
[Firebase data][1]

I have to retrieve all field from employee and store it in an array.
Now data change toast message is coming but its very late.

```
Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
            rootRef = new Firebase(
                    "https://mylink.firebaseio.com/user/employee");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "2",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            rootRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     tv1.setText("The read failed");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "failed",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                      System.out.println("The read failed: " + arg0.getMessage());
                }

                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "data change",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                  System.out.println("There are " + arg0.getChildrenCount() + " blog posts");
                  for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: arg0.getChildren()) {
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "call blogpost",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    BlogPost post = postSnapshot.getValue(BlogPost.class);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "getting value",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    System.out.println(post.getPath() + " - " + post.getSeqno());
                    tv1.setText(post.getPath() + " - " + post.getSeqno());
                  }
                }


            });
```

**BlogPost** :

```
public class BlogPost {


      private String path;
      private String dt;
      private String latitude;
      private String longitude;
      private String seqno;

      public BlogPost() {
            // empty default constructor, necessary for Firebase to be able to deserialize blog posts
          }
    public String getDateTime() {
        return dt;
    }
    public void setDateTime(String dt) {
        this.dt = dt;
    }
    public String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }
    public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }
    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }
    public void setDob(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }
    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }
    public String getSeqno() {
        return seqno;
    }
    public void setSeqno(String seqno) {
        this.seqno = seqno;
    }
    }
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?
thank you in advance.

JSON:

```
myfirebaselink
 user
  employee
    -KAZY5627P4MjLBa3Ae-
      DateTime: "2016-02-15 16:18:20"
      Latitude: "11.0318354"
      Longitude: "11.0318354"
      Path: "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/100ANDRO/DSC_0070.JPG"
      Seqno: "1"
   -KAZZcBscTCAon8ShoXa
      DateTime: "2016-02-15 16:25:02"
      Latitude: "11.0318501"
      Longitude: "11.0318501"
      Path: "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/100ANDRO/DSC_0071.JPG"
      Seqno: "2"
```

Comment: Check whether your internet permission is ON. If its on either if there is error it will should toast error or else it should toast result. Also check the url you entered

Comment: yes I gave internet permission , url also correct

Comment: have you tried rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent()
or rootRef.addChildEventListener. Just have a try.

Comment: it is also not working.. if i give another firebase url its working, but my firebase url is not working. what is the problem?

Comment: Post your JSON as text please. I'm not going to manually type it to see if your code works for me.

Comment: try one thing update your firebase record from wen and c is something is happening here

Comment: @ Frank van Puffelen  i have posted JSON

Comment: any one tell me the solution please

Comment: Is data you requested coming or is it null..?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are trying to store the retrieved data from firebase into arrays, assuming that your URL is correct and the data changes are visible. I think this is how you must get started:

```
Firebase julieRef = new Firebase("Your_URL");
julieRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
       GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>> t = new GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>>() {};
       List<String> messages = snapshot.getValue(t);
       if( messages === null ) {
          System.out.println('No messages');
       }
       else {
          System.out.println("The first message is: " + messages.get(0) );
       }
   }

   // onCancelled...
});
```

Hope this helps.